# Fetch Facebook friend list with sdks 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

```
NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[parameters setValue:@"id,name,email" forKey:@"fields"];

FBSDKGraphRequest *friendsRequest =
[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
                                      parameters:parameters];
FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];
[connection addRequest:friendsRequest
         completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *innerConnection, NSDictionary *result, NSError *error)
     {
             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
         }];
    // start the actual request
[connection start];
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: i don't able to fetch Facebook friend please tell me how is it possible ?

Comment: iam using below code but im getting null value                                                                    **FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/me"
                                  parameters:@{ @"fields": @"id,name,friendlists",}
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {
       NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
    }];**